# Why is my eOS running slow on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, amd

I'm new to the OS and to Linux in general and I would like to know why is my laptop running eOS so slow (even slower than it ran Windows)

Specs: AMD A10-8700P, 8GB DDR3, 5400RPM 1Tb HHD and Radeon R6 integrated graphics. I know it's not the best setup but I think it deserves better than what I'm getting. I disabled animations with Tweaks. Everything is slow (start, login, opening Chrome, File explorer, Discord, Spotify, etc...) Only Terminal seems to be opening instantaneously. Even closing the laptop and reopening it (waking it up) takes a whole 40 seconds or so...

Every comment is much obliged!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but my computer (lenovo ideapad 330) has also slowed down a lot and I think it was since Hera came along, because when I installed Juno everythin was so fast and instantly available, I was really pleased. Now, not so much. All that to say, you're not alone with your problem.

Comment: "running slow" is very vague and makes difficult to help you. Can you try running some tools like `top`, `iotop`, `free` and find out your computer resource usage? Generally _load_, CPU usage, RAM usage and disk IO are things you want to look for.

Comment: You may also try running https://github.com/lpereira/hardinfo to get a meaningful benchmark to tailor your performance expectations :) BTW, you state you "disabled" animations, have you tried with them enabled (seems counter-intuitive, but worth a try)?

Comment: Okay this is free: https://i.imgur.com/ZL6AmGc.jpg This is top: https://i.imgur.com/XCtQfwJ.jpg This is iotop: https://i.imgur.com/LDTAaPx.jpg And this is iotop only: https://i.imgur.com/QxKi1Z4.jpg I know it's in spanish but I hope you understand and can help me pls.

Comment: Also when I turn on my laptop everything works fine. But when I close the lid and open it later and the system wakes up I dont have Wi-Fi and I cant click any item on the top bar, I cant even turn off my laptop